# SQL Using the OR & AND operators (Newbie)

Tags: mysql, sql, operators

I am using the OR operator in the following fashion:

```
SELECT * FROM Customers
WHERE City = "Berlin" OR City = "London"
```

The above returns a results table containing some data, however what also returns data is:

```
SELECT * FROM Customers
Where City = "Berlin" OR "London"
```

I am using a questionable SQL editor currently, and want to know if this would be valid in a MySQL environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, Cassini i have check your syntax and run this query on my table i did not getting same result. I am getting correct output as expected.

i have run this command:

```
SELECT * FROM `city` where name = 'London' or 'Berlin'
```

and i got only london in name column. When i run this command:

```
SELECT * FROM `city` where name = 'London' or name = 'Berlin'
```

then i got both the cities in name column. so command is valid it will return only valid output which satisfy the condition.

So, i can say that command is valid but execute only that part of query which satisfy MYSQL Select syntax.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for

```
SELECT * FROM Customers Where City IN('Berlin', 'London');
```

The query:

```
Where City='Berlin' OR 'London'
```

Applies the [logical OR operator (||)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/logical-operators.html#operator_or), so `OR "London"` is equivalent to `OR 0`, and `Where City = 'Berlin' OR 0;` will just return `'Berlin'`

[SqlFiddle here with truth table here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4b8ae/7)

Minor, but you should look at using [single quotes for string literals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-backticks), as this is more portable between RDBMS's and use of `"` will depend on [`ANSI QUOTES`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_ansi_quotes).

Comment: Thanks, If i'd had a better reputation around here I would have given you an up vote.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if it valid in SQL, it should be valid in MySQL to. Are you wondering if this would be valid in MYSQL

```
SELECT * FROM Customers Where City="Berlin" OR"London"
```

It should be valid in MySQL

Hope that helps. If it does not, add a comment

Answer (score 0):

this returnd the same values as your first sql-string.

But your first string is more readable for others.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `IN`

```
SELECT * 
FROM Customers
Where City IN ("Berlin","London")
```